# Taking a Sequence To Generate a valid input for that sequence

Tags: bash, if-statement, random, generator, sequence

So Here is What i am trying to make first if possible a way to get an if statement from a file and then look at what would be an input that would be true and generate that valid input here is what i have come up with so far
this is the test file first A.K.A Test.sh oh btw a Valid input example is 1file and then the other number/letters are just optional

```
input=
if [[ $input = [0-9]@(|[0-9]@(|[0-9]))File@(|[0-9]@(|[0-9]@(|[0-9]@(|[a-z]@(|[a-z]@(|[a-z])))))) ]]; then
echo "Good"
  else
echo "Bad"
fi
```

Then what the actual code What i will call the input generator so currently what is does is it counts how many numbers there are or could be in the sequence however from there I don't know what i should do to make this actually generate a valid input now i don't need it to read a the test file I'm fine with it being in the same file as the test with the sequence

```
file=test.sh
N="\[0-9]"
Al='\[a-z]'
Au='\[A-Z]'
ifstat=$(grep -w if $file)
amn=$(echo "$ifstat" | grep -o "$N" | wc -l)
echo "$amn"
```

so in summary i want it a generator to make a random input for that if statement that would be "Good"

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To help us help you, can you please clean up the structure a bit and make it clearer what your question is?

Comment: You want a command that can read a regex and generate a string that would be matched by that regexp? Good luck....

Comment: Hi so wanted basically a script to make an input that would be valid for the test script or the first block of code some thing like a number generator but would generate valid inputs for script 1

Comment: Did you consider searching for such a thing online? The internet seems to be catching on.... https://www.google.com/search?q=generate+text+that+would+match+a+regexp&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8